# PN532 NFC - Returning more than 256 bytes from inDataExchange call to Android HCE

Tags: android, nfc, apdu, hce, pn532

Reading the last paragraph of the following it looks like there is a way to send large blocks of data in response to an NFC issuing an inDataExchange call by breaking it up into small chunks:

> 3.3.7.4 Transfer of large amount of data

> Chaining mechanism
>
> - from initiator to target:
>   Large amount of data are sent by the initiator with InDataExchange function, in packets
>   of 252 bytes of data. The initiator must send InDataExchange command as many times
>   as necessary to transfer the complete amount of data.
>   The target must perform TgGetData and TgSetData functions as many times as
>   necessary to retrieve all packets sent by the initiator.

> Metachaining mechanism
>
> - From initiator to target:
>   One bit called MI (more information), in InDataExchange first parameter, indicates to the
>   target if data received are part of a large block. In that case, the target can directly
>   continue the exchange with TgGetData (no TgSetData needed).
> - From target to initiator:
>   The target can provide the initiator with large amount of data using TgSetMetaData
>   function. The initiator has sent a InDataExchange function. The response to the initiator
>   is sent via TgSetMetaData function instead of TgSetData function. In that case, one bit
>   indicates to the initiator that some data are still available at target side. The initiator shall
>   go on with a InDataExchange function (with no data sent from the intiator to the target).
>   Last packet of data will be transferred with TgSetData function.
>   Refer to the PN532 User manual (reference 1) for detailed explanation.

When I do a "normal" response to an APDU call in my Android HCE, it looks something like this:

```
private static final byte[] SELECT_OK_SW = HexStringToByteArray("9000");
private static final byte[] UNKNOWN_CMD_SW = HexStringToByteArray("0000");
@Override
    public byte[] processCommandApdu(byte[] commandApdu, Bundle extras) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Received APDU: " + ByteArrayToHexString(commandApdu));
        // If the APDU matches the SELECT AID command for this service,
        // send the account name, followed by a SELECT_OK status trailer (0x9000).
        if (Arrays.equals(SELECT_APDU, commandApdu)) {
            String account="Tommyburger";
            byte[] accountBytes = account.getBytes();
            Log.d(TAG, "Sending account number: " + account);
            return ConcatArrays(accountBytes, SELECT_OK_SW);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "AID didn't match");
            return UNKNOWN_CMD_SW;
        }
    }
```

Looking at the "command constants" from the 532.h file:

```
// PN532 Commands
#define PN532_COMMAND_DIAGNOSE              (0x00)
#define PN532_COMMAND_GETFIRMWAREVERSION    (0x02)
#define PN532_COMMAND_GETGENERALSTATUS      (0x04)
#define PN532_COMMAND_READREGISTER          (0x06)
#define PN532_COMMAND_WRITEREGISTER         (0x08)
#define PN532_COMMAND_READGPIO              (0x0C)
#define PN532_COMMAND_WRITEGPIO             (0x0E)
#define PN532_COMMAND_SETSERIALBAUDRATE     (0x10)
#define PN532_COMMAND_SETPARAMETERS         (0x12)
#define PN532_COMMAND_SAMCONFIGURATION      (0x14)
#define PN532_COMMAND_POWERDOWN             (0x16)
#define PN532_COMMAND_RFCONFIGURATION       (0x32)
#define PN532_COMMAND_RFREGULATIONTEST      (0x58)
#define PN532_COMMAND_INJUMPFORDEP          (0x56)
#define PN532_COMMAND_INJUMPFORPSL          (0x46)
#define PN532_COMMAND_INLISTPASSIVETARGET   (0x4A)
#define PN532_COMMAND_INATR                 (0x50)
#define PN532_COMMAND_INPSL                 (0x4E)
#define PN532_COMMAND_INDATAEXCHANGE        (0x40)
#define PN532_COMMAND_INCOMMUNICATETHRU     (0x42)
#define PN532_COMMAND_INDESELECT            (0x44)
#define PN532_COMMAND_INRELEASE             (0x52)
#define PN532_COMMAND_INSELECT              (0x54)
#define PN532_COMMAND_INAUTOPOLL            (0x60)
#define PN532_COMMAND_TGINITASTARGET        (0x8C)
#define PN532_COMMAND_TGSETGENERALBYTES     (0x92)
#define PN532_COMMAND_TGGETDATA             (0x86)
#define PN532_COMMAND_TGSETDATA             (0x8E)
#define PN532_COMMAND_TGSETMETADATA         (0x94)
#define PN532_COMMAND_TGGETINITIATORCOMMAND (0x88)
#define PN532_COMMAND_TGRESPONSETOINITIATOR (0x90)
#define PN532_COMMAND_TGGETTARGETSTATUS     (0x8A)
#define PN532_RESPONSE_INDATAEXCHANGE       (0x41)
#define PN532_RESPONSE_INLISTPASSIVETARGET  (0x4B)
```

It would seem that I usually do the TGRESPONSETOINITIATOR command 0x9000 as SELECT_OK_SW in Android HCE.  So to send, for example, 1k bytes, I would break it up into blocks of 256 bytes (or a little smaller) and send with TGSETMETADATA command byte 0x9400, except the the last block, which would use TGSETDATA command byte 0x8E00? Has anyone done this before?